# Text shifts when opening/closing the menu but it shouldn't

Tags: html, css

I'm building a slide menu but it wouldn't work (even though I followed a tutorial).

I'm opening the menu with a js function that sets menu width and marginLeft to 300px on click. I'm closing it by setting those 2 values to 0.

When I'm opening/closing the menu, the menu text (see pictures below) with 2 or more words shifts (extra words shift down). I've tried a few display options (block, flex, grid, etc.) and setting the overflow to hidden - none of those tweaks worked for me.

```
.navigation a {
display: block;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 25px;
color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
text-decoration: none;
```

This is how menu text should look like all the time:

[image]

This is how the menu text looks like when opening and closing the menu:

[image]

Comment: Use `white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: clip;`

Comment: @ChloeAnderson this worked flawlessly., thank you! May i ask what does "white-space: nowrap" do?

Comment: It manages how spaces should be broken down. `nowrap` tells it to not break into a new line, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space